# Aliases for Networking Commands

Tags: linux, systemd, alias, bashrc, sysvinit

I need to run a legacy script on some newer systems, without installing packages or loading binaries.  The script uses some of the older networking and SysV init commands.  Is there a set of aliases that I could simply append to the bashrc, for example to drive these equivalent systemd commands https://www.2daygeek.com/sysvinit-vs-systemd-cheatsheet-systemctl-command-usage/?  I understand that the older commands are deprecated, it does not need to translate exactly to be production safe.

I understand that some output-oriented commands are different, eg. ip addr vs. ifconfig.  Is it possible to also get the old style output?

Comment: which of these older commands are now missing and need to be translated for your script?

Comment: At least ifconfig, service.

Comment: service being a wrapper for init scripts, you may need to list the service names being invoked, if they're not proprietary to your environment. They may or may not have systemd correspondents.